# How to write sql query where the WHERE clause uses a substring casted to a long?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table called "accounts" there is an account id that is a 13 character long string, where the first 8 digits are the user id who owns that account. How do I query the database with an integer and check the first 8 characters only?

I was trying to do something like this:

`SELECT * FROM networthr.accounts WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(account_id, 0, 8) as long) = 1;`

But it won't even let me run this query.

Comment: How does an `account_id` look like? Is it zero padded like `00000001ABCDE`?

Comment: an id would look like "000000010001" where user id = 1 and the following 4 digits represent an account id

Comment: You really should split them into two columns. And maybe create a *generated* column for the combined value. That would make many things simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your query:
1) The 2nd argument of `SUBSTRING()` should be 1 (the index is 1 based not 0 based)
2) You should cast to the data type `UNSIGNED`

```
SELECT * FROM networthr.accounts WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(account_id, 1, 8) as unsigned ) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bad design. However - If the `account_id` is zero padded like "00000001ABCDE" and you have an index on it, an efficient way would be

```
SELECT *
FROM networthr.accounts
WHERE account_id LIKE CONCAT(LPAD(?, 8, 0), '%')
```

Replace `?` with the `user_id` or use it as a prepared statement and bind `user_id` as parameter.

In case of `user_id = 1` it's the same as

```
WHERE account_id LIKE '00000001%'
```

Comment: great - the best way to use the index. The other answers are always a full table scan

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit conversion:

```
WHERE LEFT(account_id, 8) + 0 = 1
```

However, you should really be comparing strings to string.